# How do I get rid of box rust in December? Will fungicide work?

Tags: diseases, boxwood, rust

I have two buxus which have suffered a lack of water due to irrigation failing in the summer and no time to hand water them. There is a definite orange tinge to the first 2 or 3 inches of top growth. I fear pruning at this time of year will kill them. Will a good fungicide at least kill the disease. Advice please? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With the Buxus or Boxwood it is very common for the plant to discolor in winter, especially if they're not protected from the sun and wind.

I would bet you're experiencing drying and not rust. A picture would confirm that though.